# Probability of throwing a rigged dice

Tags: probability

We have two dices, one is standard (so faces from $1$ to $6$). And the other one is rigged and has all faces with $6$ dots. What is the probability that we are holding the standard dice if we throw a dice $k$ times and every time there are $6$ dots being thrown.

My understanding (Do not know where I got it wrong):

If we want to know what is the probability that we throw a $6$:

$$P(\text{throwing a 6}) = P(\text{standard dice})\cdot P(\text{throwing a 6 on a standard}) + P(\text{rigged dice})\cdot P(\text{rigged dice shows 6})$$
so we get:
$$P(\text{throwing a 6}) =1/2 \cdot1/6 + 1/2 \cdot 6/6 = 7/12$$
if we want to know what is the probability that the $6$ that we thrown came from the standard dice :
$$\frac{P(\text{standard dice})\cdot P(\text{throwing a 6 on a standard})}{P(\text{throwing a 6})} = \frac{1}{7}$$

Okay, now if we want to know if we thrown a standard dice $k$ times where $6$ dots were shown we can do : $A_k = (\frac{1}{7})^k = \frac{1}{7^k}$

However this is not the correct answer. The solution should be:

$$\frac{P(\text{standard dice})\cdot P(\text{throwing a 6 on a standard})}{P(\text{throwing a 6})} = \frac{(1/6)^k\cdot (1/2)}{(1/6)^k \cdot (1/2) + 1 \cdot (1/2)} = \frac{1}{1+6^k}$$

Howevere I do not understand the difference between the solution and my understanding. Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: Do you choose between the two dice at once before the $k$ rolls, or do you get to re-choose again before each new roll? I think the difference may come from that.

Comment: @nejimban so it would be $\frac{1}{7^k}$ if we re-choose and the other answer if we choose only once, if I understand correctly?

Comment: Yes, I think so.